# How to get only HMS formatting in x-axis pandas (matplotlib) plot

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, pandas, axis-labels, timedelta

I'm trying to plot temperature measurements taken over a few hours.  My data file contains the time in milliseconds.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from pandas import to_timedelta
import pandas as pd
import datetime DT
df = pd.read_csv('temperature_measurements.txt')
my_columns=['time_ms','tempC','humidity']
df.columns = my_columns

#remove timestamp offset
startTime = df['time_ms'].min()
#get time in seconds, round off because I was getting >2 significant figuress
df['time_s']=np.round((df['time_ms']-startTime)/1000)

#convert to datetime object
df['time']=pd.to_timedelta((df['time_s']),unit='s')
df.plot(x='time',y='tempC')
```

I get a plot where the x axis ranges from "0 days 00:00:00" to "0 days 01:14:11".
I want to truncate this to show only HH:MM:SS (e.g. 00:00:00 to 1:14:11). How can I remove the "0 days"  prefix in the x-axis?  Also, is there a simpler pd command to convert data to HMS objects?
Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Thanks to @HYRY here is my final code

```
plt.plot(df.time, df.tempC)
ax = plt.gca()
tick_labels = ax.xaxis.major.formatter.seq
ax.xaxis.major.formatter.seq = [label.split()[-1] if label else "" for label in tick_labels]
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code after `df.plot(x='time',y='tempC')`:

```
tick_labels = ax.xaxis.major.formatter.seq
ax.xaxis.major.formatter.seq = [label.split()[-1] if label else "" for label in tick_labels]
```

Comment: Thanks @HYRY this worked for me! I had to add ax = plt.gca() (need to add a line to define ax.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure() # creates matplotlib figure object
plt.plot(df.time, df.tempC) # plots x, y
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90) # rotates the date to 90 degree to make it look better
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I get 'Figure' object has no attribute 'autofmtxdate' error. Thanks to  @user1324362 solved quickly and elegantly)

Comment: you have to add import matplotlib.pyplot as plt in the import statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KirubaharanJ but I still get the same error 'Figure' object has no attribute 'autofmtxdata' if I import the matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: sorry you have to use fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90), I corrected my answer